# check number of elements in list A present in list B java

Tags: java, collections

I have two lists (arraylists) and I would like to know effective way to check number of elements of List A present in List B.

```
List<String> listA = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> listB = new ArrayList<>();
```

I would like to know how many elements in **listA**  are present in **listB**

I can loop over and check but I am looking for an effective and fastest way I can do using java 1.8

Thanks for help.

Comment: What have tried so far?

Comment: @akortex I have tried looping over manually  and checking ...  it worked.. but i need a faster or any proven  inbuilt API  method if any

Comment: How are duplicates supposed to be handled?

Comment: My both lists doesn't have duplicates

Comment: One liner: `Set<Integer> intersection = Sets.intersection(new HashSet<>(a), new HashSet<>(b)).immutableCopy();` but you need to add a dependency to guava.

Comment: Thanks Matteo.. adding a dependency for just small functionality is not encouraged in my org..   i guess java should be now matured enough to handle such trivial stuff..  thanks anyways for ur reply.

Comment: @Stunner sure it makes sense more if you already use guava than adding it just for that. Even though keep in mind that libraries like guava (provided by Google) are very mature and efficient libraries which provide powerful utilities that otherwise you should maintain on your own and yet, doubtfully you'd get the same degree of speed and stability because.. it's Google :)

Comment: agreed @MatteoNNZ :)

Comment: Java8 is NOT a silver bullet that solves all your problems !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another easy approach without looping and without creating a third list could be the following:

```java
var listA = new ArrayList<>(list1);
var listB = new ArrayList<>(list2);
listB.retainAll(listA);
System.out.println(listB);
```

Note that this approach assumes that there are no duplicates in the list but should this be the case, you can simply create two sets out of the lists on hand and apply the same approach.

Comment: This runs in quadratic time. So for a large data set it takes more time.

Answer (score 1):

You can create third list which contain the same content of listA, then remove listB from the new list and then you can distinct how many elements in listA are present in listB like this:

```
List<String> listC = new ArrayList<>(listA);
listC.removeAll(listB);
int elementsPresentInListB = listA.size() - listC.size();
```

Comment: This runs in quadratic time. So for a large data set it takes more time.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is just to find the size of the set intersection. You can create a set from `listB`. Then iterate over each element in `listA` and check for it's containment in the set. The set contains takes O(1) time for a hash-based set. So, this takes O(n) time and space complexity. Here's how it looks.

```
final Set<String> setB = new HashSet<>(listB);
int c = 0;
for (String string : listA)
    if (setB.contains(string))
        c = c + 1;
```

A more succinct solution would be:

```
setB.retainAll(listA);
c = setB.size();
```

This operation effectively modifies this set so that its value is the intersection of the two sets.

Comment: Your interpretation of similarity is completely wrong here, mine uses a set where as the other uses a list. That use of a set brings otherwise quadratic time solution down to a linear time one. Please read it carefully, they are different entities like apples and oranges after all.

Comment: I removed my comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8's Stream API, you can use the following to get the intersection of your two lists:

```java
Set<String> intersection = listA.stream()   // creates stream
                                .distinct() // filters out any duplicates
                                .filter(listB::contains) // filters the intersection
                                .collect(Collectors.toSet()); // reduces to set
int amount = intersection.size(); // your amount of duplicate elements
```

Comment: This runs in quadratic time. So for a large data set it takes more time.